# How to add an action Listener in DefaultListModel and not in JList

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I have the following code and i add elements to a `JList`.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
listModel.addElement("element1");
listModel.addElement("element2");
listModel.addElement("element3");
list = new JList(listModel);
list.addListSelectionListener(this);
```

In **another method** of my code

- I remove all the elements of listModel(`DefaultListModel`) and
- I add the elements of a `SortedSet`: (*`listModel` is a `public static` variable)*

  ```
  listModel.removeAllElements();
  SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(myHashMap.keySet());
      Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          String key = it.next();
          listModel.addElement(key);
          //How can i add an addActionListener to every 'key element'
          //since the JList list variable is not global ??
      }
  ```

Since **'list'** is **not** a public static variable, how can I add an Action Listener
to each one of the list Items in the listModel?

I tried to use an `addListDataListener`, but I don't think that is use for the purpose that I need.

Comment: What do you want to listen? Everytime a jlist item is selected? or data in your jlist(in the model) is modified?

Comment: everytime a jlist item is selected

Comment: ListSelectionListener is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use the concepts presented in [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/). It will execute an Acton on an item in the JList when you double click on the item or use the Enter key on the selected item.

Or if you just want to know when an item is selected by a single mouse click or by using the up/down arrow keys then you should be using a `ListSelectionListener`. See [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html).

Comment: Well i used the ListSelectionListener but i get the following exception:java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.DefaultListModel cannot be cast to javax.swing.ListSelectionModel, that happens because in my method i don't have access to the JList object but only to the DefaultListModel, so in my case it's not working, so what can i do?

Comment: @programmer, `i don't have access to the JList object but only to the DefaultListModel,` - then change your code so that you do have access to the JList. Either you make the JList an instance variable or you can always pass in the JList as a parameter when you create your custom ListSelectionListener.

Comment: I agree that it would be better to pass the JList as a parameter, but i don't really know how to insert/add every element of the for loop in the Jlist. e.g. `String[] myarray = {"item1","item2"}; JList mylist = new JList(myarray); /* common way of creating a JList*/` ,how can i update an already created JList? that is my problem...

Comment: @programmer i don't get it what you want, for what purpose do you need your JList?

Comment: @programmer, I have no idea what you are talking about. `A ListSelectionListener is added to a JList`. It has nothing to do with how you add items to the list or how many items are in the list. When the selection event occurs, you get the index of the item selected, then you can get the actual item from either the JList or the ListModel. Then you do some processing on the item.

Comment: I solved my problem now,i made the JList variable accessible to everyone and then after the for loop i added the following: `list.setModel(listModel);       list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() { etc..`

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need:

List selection events occur when the selection
in a list or table is either changing or has just
changed. List selection events are fired from
an object that implements the
ListSelectionModel interface. To get a table's
list selection model object, you can use either
getSelectionModel method or
getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html